Recent progress about conservativity conjectures on the motives realizations
Let $k$ be a field and $\text{DM}_\text{gm}(k,\Lambda)$ be the category of geometric motives. As in the https://user.math.uzh.ch/ayoub/PDF-Files/Article-for-Steven.pdf , the conservativity conjectures considering the betti realization functors $\text{DM}_\text{gm}(k,\Lambda)\longrightarrow\text{D}(\Lambda)$ where $\Lambda$ is the coefficients ring.
Is there any recent progress on this conjectures? All I know is the $l$-adic realization for abelian varieties over finite fields and the topologie feuilletée et la conservativité des réalisations classiques en caractéristique nulle with a gap. What's the recent situation on this paper by Joseph Ayoub, will the gap be fixed soon?

To my best knowledge, there is no recent progress on the conservativity conjecture. However Ayoub proved an interesting result that the Betti realization over $\mathbb{Q}$ yields a motivic Galois group, which coincides with the one defined by Nori.
